# Adding together calculated variables

Tags: jquery

I am creating a price table where I i calculate a subtotal price for two ticket types based on a fixed price and the number of tickets they select.
These two functions are working as they should.
Afterwards I would like to calculate the grand total by adding together the the two subtotals. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="ticket-cat">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p id="price-adult" data-price="12.77">€ 12.77</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <select class="tickets-selection form-control" value="0" name="ticket-select-adult" id="ticket-select-adult">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p id="adult-total" class="text-right">
        <span class="valuta hidden">€</span>
        <span class="total"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="ticket-cat">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p id="price-student" data-price="9.41">€ 9.41</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <select class="tickets-selection form-control" value="0" name="ticket-select-student" id="ticket-select-student">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p id="student-total" class="text-right">
        <span class="valuta hidden">€</span>
        <span class="total hidden"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    var $adultTotal = $("#adult-total .total");
    var adultPrice = parseFloat($("#price-adult").data("price"));

    // Fixes NaN and calculates the total price for adult tickets
    $('#ticket-select-adult').change(function () {
        var adultTicketsCount = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        var adultPriceTotal = isNaN(adultTicketsCount) ?
            ' n/a ' :
            (adultTicketsCount * adultPrice).toFixed(2);
        $adultTotal.text(adultPriceTotal);
    });

    var $studentTotal = $("#student-total .total");
    var studentPrice = parseFloat($("#price-student").data("price"));

    // Fixes NaN and calculates the total price for student tickets
    $('#ticket-select-student').change(function () {
        var studentTicketsCount = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        var studentPriceTotal = isNaN(studentTicketsCount) ?
            ' n/a ' :
            (studentTicketsCount * studentPrice).toFixed(2);
        $studentTotal.text(studentPriceTotal);
    });

    // Add together the variables 
    totalPriceTickets = 0;
    totalPriceTickets = parseInt(adultPriceTotal) + parseInt(studentPriceTotal);
    console.log(totalPriceTickets, "Hello, world!");

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mckeene/rLnv348x/

Comment: Can you please share the HTML too?

Comment: @JamyGolden Yeah, I have added the HTML and a JSFiddle now. As mentioned the select and calculating subtotal is working fine. My problem is defining the totalPriceTickets variable as a sum of the other variables.

Comment: @JamyGolden How do I make sure that the totalPriceTickets and total are defined to have two decimals?

Comment: I suggest you create new stackoverflow questions when you have an unrelated question. `number.toFixed(2)` will return a string version of what you're looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the problems were due to variable's being out of scope, so I've defined them at the top. A `console.log()` of the total should display each time a value is changed. This was another one of your problems, the total was being displayed initially rather than each time the values were changed.

```
$(function () {
    var $adultTotal = $("#adult-total .total");
    var adultPrice = parseFloat($("#price-adult").data("price"));
    var $studentTotal = $("#student-total .total");
    var studentPrice = parseFloat($("#price-student").data("price"));
    var adultPriceTotal = 0;
    var studentPriceTotal = 0;
    var totalPriceTickets = null;

    // Fixes NaN and calculates the total price for adult tickets
    $('#ticket-select-adult').change(function () {
        var adultTicketsCount = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        adultPriceTotal = isNaN(adultTicketsCount) ?
            0 :
            (adultTicketsCount * adultPrice).toFixed(2);
        $adultTotal.text(adultPriceTotal);

        totalPriceTickets = calculateTotal(adultPriceTotal, studentPriceTotal);
    });

    // Fixes NaN and calculates the total price for student tickets
    $('#ticket-select-student').change(function () {
        var studentTicketsCount = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        studentPriceTotal = isNaN(studentTicketsCount) ?
            0 :
            (studentTicketsCount * studentPrice).toFixed(2);
        $studentTotal.text(studentPriceTotal);

        totalPriceTickets = calculateTotal(adultPriceTotal, studentPriceTotal);
    });

    function calculateTotal(adultPriceTotal, studentPriceTotal) {
        var total = parseInt(adultPriceTotal) + parseInt(studentPriceTotal);

        console.log(total)
        return total;
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :)